# how to Get email alert when the website is up using python

Tags: python

```
import smtplib, requests, time
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart

while(1):
    try:
        # Replace the url for your desired website
        url = "https://www.facebook.com/"

        # Send the get request to the website
        r = requests.get(url)

        # creates SMTP session
        s = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)

        # start TLS for security
        s.starttls()

        # Authentication
        s.login("sender_gmail_id", "sender_password")

        # Instance of MIMEMultipart
        msg = MIMEMultipart("alternative")

        # Write the subject
        msg["Subject"]= url + " is working now."

        msg["From"]="sender_gmail_id"
        msg["To"]="receiver_gmail_id"

        # Plain text body of the mail
        text = url + " is running now."

        # Attach the Plain body with the msg instance
        msg.attach(MIMEText(text, "plain"))

        # HTML body of the mail
        html ="<h2>Your site is running now.</h2><br/><a href ='"
            + url + "'>Click here to visit.</a>"

        # Attach the HTML body with the msg instance
        msg.attach(MIMEText(html, "html"))

        # Sending the mail
        s.sendmail("sender_gmail_id", "receiver_gmail_id", msg.as_string())
        s.quit()
        print('sent')
        break
    except:
        print('site is down yet...')
        print('sleeping...')

        # Sleeping for 60 seconds. We can change this interval.
        time.sleep(60)
        print('Trying again')
        continue
```

Comment: Please add your question.

Comment: Please use common worded language patterns in a human-readable way and in adherence to international standards and regulations on language and grammar usage in written structures or in spoken dialogue, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First install [quick-mailer module](https://pypi.org/project/quick-mailer/):

> pip install quick-mailer

```
import socket
import time

from mailer import Mailer


def is_site_up(url: str) -> bool:
    with socket.socket() as s:
        try:
            s.connect((url, 80))
            s.sendall(b'GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n')
            response = s.recv(26)
            if not (b'200' in response):
                raise socket.error
            return True
        except socket.error:
            return False


def check(url: str, interval: int) -> None:
    while True:
        if is_site_up(url):
            mail = Mailer(email='someone@gamil.com',
                          password='your_password')

            mail.send(receiver='someone@example.com',
                      subject=f'{url} is working now.',
                      message=f"<h2>Your site is running now.</h2><br/><a href ='{url}'>Click here to visit.</a>")
            print('Site is up...', mail.status)
            break
        else:
            print('Site is down yet...')
        time.sleep(interval)


check('www.google.com', interval=10)
```

Or you can use `requests` instead of `sockets`:

```
from requests.exceptions import BaseHTTPError
import requests


def is_site_up(url: str) -> bool:
    try:
        with requests.get(url) as resp:
            if resp.status_code != 200:
                raise BaseHTTPError()
        return True
    except BaseHTTPError:
        return False
```